# Counting dates that fall between two dates in the same column

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two tables and for each ID and Level combination in table1, I need to get a count of times matching ID appears in table2 in between sequential times for levels in table1.

So for example, for ID = 1 and Level=1 in table1, two Time entries from table2 for ID=1 fall between Time of Level=1 and Level=2 in table1, so result will be 2 in the result table.

```
table1:

ID  Level   Time
1   1   6/7/13 7:03
1   2   6/9/13 7:05
1   3   6/12/13 12:02
1   4   6/17/13 5:01
2   1   6/18/13 8:38
2   3   6/20/13 9:38
2   4   6/23/13 10:38
2   5   6/28/13 1:38

table2:

ID  Time
1   6/7/13 11:51
1   6/7/13 14:15
1   6/9/13 16:39
1   6/9/13 19:03
2   6/20/13 11:02
2   6/20/13 15:50
```

Result would be

```
ID  Level   Count
1   1   2
1   2   2
1   3   0
1   4   0
2   1   0
2   3   2
2   4   0
2   5   0
```

Comment: Have you tried `lag` or `lead` functions to get next/previous values of `Time`?

Answer (score 1):

```
select transformed_tab1.id, transformed_tab1.level, count(tab2.id)
from
(select tab1.id, tab1.level, tm, lead(tm) over (partition by id order by tm) as next_tm
from
(
select 1 as id, 1 as level, '2013-06-07 07:03'::timestamp as tm union
select 1 as id, 2 as level, '2013-06-09 07:05 '::timestamp as tm union
select 1 as id, 3 as level, '2013-06-12 12:02'::timestamp as tm union
select 1 as id, 4 as level, '2013-06-17 05:01'::timestamp as tm union
select 2 as id, 1 as level, '2013-06-18 08:38'::timestamp as tm union
select 2 as id, 3 as level, '2013-06-20 09:38'::timestamp as tm union
select 2 as id, 4 as level, '2013-06-23 10:38'::timestamp as tm union
select 2 as id, 5 as level, '2013-06-28 01:38'::timestamp as tm) tab1
) transformed_tab1
left join
(select 1 as id, '2013-06-07 11:51'::timestamp as tm union
select 1 as id, '2013-06-07 14:15'::timestamp as tm union
select 1 as id, '2013-06-09 16:39'::timestamp as tm union
select 1 as id, '2013-06-09 19:03'::timestamp as tm union
select 2 as id, '2013-06-20 11:02'::timestamp as tm union
select 2 as id, '2013-06-20 15:50'::timestamp as tm) tab2
on transformed_tab1.id=tab2.id and tab2.tm between transformed_tab1.tm and transformed_tab1.next_tm
group by transformed_tab1.id, transformed_tab1.level
order by transformed_tab1.id, transformed_tab1.level
;
```

Answer (score -1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2cd91/3)

```
select t1.id, level, count(t2.id)
from
    (
        select id, level,
            tsrange(
                "time",
                lead("time", 1, 'infinity') over(
                    partition by id order by level
                    ),
                '[)'
            ) as time_range
        from t1
    ) t1
    left join
    t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.time_range @> t2."time"
group by t1.id, level
order by t1.id, level
```

The solution starts creating a range of timestamps using the `lead` window function. Notice the `[)` parameter to the `tsrange` constructor. It means to include the lower and exclude the upper bound.

Then it joins the two tables with the `@>` range operator. It means the range includes the element.

It is necessary to `left join` t1 to have the zero counts.

Comment: I believe that should work fine but just found out that we use Amazon Redsfhit and some functions are not supported.  For lead function, I get error message "Default parameter not supported for window function lead" and tsrange function does not exist.  I will try to see if there is a workaround. Thanks!